# Expressing lack of opinion of a binary question

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose that my friend asks me if I want to see a movie, and that I have no strong opinion.
I do not particularly want to go, but I do not not want to go, either.
I am not trying to please my friend by letting him decide; I just have no opinion on whether to go or not.
How can I express such a lack of opinion or desire in Latin?

I am not looking for anything too elaborate, but just a simple response like "either way" or "whatever".
It does not have to be as simple as my examples, but something that would feel fluent in everyday speech.
(These English phrases may not be a perfect fit, but that is beside the point.)

I might say something like *nec volo nec nolo* or pehraps *quidquid vis*.
These should be understandable, but I would like to know if there are good idioms for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Latin has a great pronoun for binary situations: *uter* (negative: *neuter*). Although your question specifically asks about "not caring," I will show these pronouns used for three situations:

1. I want both equally

> Phil. Amandone exorarier vis ted an osculando?
>   Lib. Enim véro **utrumque.** (Plautus, *Asinaria* 687-688)
>
> *Phil. Do you wish to be begged with love or with kisses?
>
>    Lib. Indeed, [I'd like] both!*

2. I hate both equally

> Ples. ...opta ocius:
>   rapi te obtorto collo mavis an trahi?
>   utrum vis opta, dum licet. Labr. **Neutrum volo.** (Plautus, *Rudens* 853-854)
>
> *Ples. ...choose quickly:
>
>   Would you prefer to be seized or dragged by your twisted neck?
>
>   Choose either, while you can. Labr. **I want neither.***

3. It doesn't matter

*Utrumvis*:

> **Mihi utrumvis satis est** et tum hoc tum illud probabilius videtur nec praeterea quicquam probabile. (Cicero, *De Officiis* 3.33)
>
> ***Either is satisfactory to me***: both this and that seem fairly probable, and beyond them there isn't any probable alternative.

*Utrumlibet*:

> **Vtrumlibet elige**; alterum incredibile est, alterum nefarium, et ante hoc tempus utrumque inauditum. (Cicero, *Pro Quinctio* 80.6)
>
> ***Choose either.***; The one option is incredible, the other is criminal, and before this time both were unheard of.

I think this last word really captures the idea of "whatever" when faced with two options:

> *Quid mavis? -**Utrumlibet!***

Note that it isn't a terribly common word,  and I'm sure there are other, perhaps more idiomatic ways of conveying the same thing.

Comment: Some living Latinists also say *susque deque*, but I don't know whether this is attested or synthetic.